# Double emails sent from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-plugins

i have configured email-ext and it work ok. Then i install Build flow plug-in and configure some jobs. It Works but Send me 2 emails after completed.

For test i create new Build flow job and in it i Build one job. Then on post Build actions i configure email-ext for sucess and receive 2 emails. Can anyone help mi with this?  Below i send logs from Build flow job

```
Started by user Dawid Wybierek
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building on master in workspace C:\Users\poca\.jenkins\workspace\testy\Test flow
No emails were triggered.
Schedule job testy » Test email
Build testy » Test email #2 started
testy » Test email #2 completed 
Email was triggered for: Success
Sending email for trigger: Success
Sending email to: dawid.wybierek@***.com
Email was triggered for: Success
Sending email for trigger: Success
Sending email to: dawid.wybierek@***.com
Finished: Success
```

config :

[screen from email ext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYl9s.png)

Comment: When you open advance in the email ext. - you have options for sending, some option to send when a specific status is achieved. look there, see that you didn't define 2 overlapping configurations

Comment: You mean triggers ? I have configure only one trigger, for sucess and Then email ext should Send email to recipant list. I can paste img with config tomorrow. I fund workaround for  now. I simply add New job to buildflow only for notification but i want to know what im doing wrong.